# Django Rest Framework: Second parameter in url being constructed with a dot (.) instead of /

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-rest-viewsets, django-url-reverse

I've got the following method in my View:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['delete'])
def remove(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
    print("here")
```

I've created a test for this endpoint. But haven't been able to get the correct url.

When I do

```
url = reverse('order-remove', kwargs={'pk':1234, 'product_id':1})
```

I get the following error:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'order-remove' with
> a keyword arguments ... not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ...

and when I try:

```
pk=1234
product_id=1
url = reverse('order-remove', args=(pk, product_id,))
```

I got the following url:

`/orders/1234/remove.1`

instead of what I'd be expecting which is: `orders/1234/remove/4` with an `/` instead of `.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try(check) this:

**urls.py**:

```
url(r'^orders/remove/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', 'views.remove', name='order_remove'),
```

**views.py:**

```
    ....
    reverse('order_remove', kwargs={'pk':1,'product_id': 12})
```

**Output:**

> orders/remove/1/12/

Comment: but that's not the url pattern I'm looking for. The one you're suggesting is `orders/remove/1/12` which is a wrong patter. The one I'm looking for is `/orders/{order_id}/remove/{item_id}`. Thanks

Comment: @TroyMcClure share your urls in this question

Comment: found the issue. I needed to add `url_path` to my action, so it ended up being: `@action(detail=True, methods=['post'], url_path='remove/(?P<pid>\d+)')`. Thanks